# how to assign values to a list in duplicated dictionary without changing the original dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
d = {1:[]}
dic = d.copy()
dic[1].append(2)

print "d=", d
print "dic=", dic
```

#### output

```
d= {1:[2]}
dic= {1:[2]}
```

How to assign `dic` without changing `d` and return

```
d= {1:[]}
dic= {1:[2]}
```

Comment: `copy.deepcopy` since `copy` doesn't make a copy of each item inside the dictionary, it just copies the references ie a shallow copy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`copy.deepcopy()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy):

```
In [5]: import copy

In [6]: d = {1:[]}

In [7]: dic = copy.deepcopy(d)

In [8]: dic[1].append(2)

In [9]: d
Out[9]: {1: []}

In [10]: dic
Out[10]: {1: [2]}
```

What you have right now is a *shallow* copy: it just makes a copy of the list *reference*. As a result, if you change the contents of the list in one dictionary, it changes in the other too.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `deepcopy` function (instead of `copy`) to make a new dictionary same as `d`. Don't forget to import it by `from copy import deepcopy`.

Comment: This is wrong, you don't make a new reference to the dict. To make a new reference is simply `d2 = d1` You copy the references to the objects inside it in a new dictionary. [*A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in the original.*](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html)

Comment: @jamylak Yes, It was my mistake, Thanks for you notice.